# Is it possible to have the fireplace and chimney put up against a supporting/load bearing column?

Tags: fireplace

I am planning to build a new house, but I have a question regarding a fireplace I want to have in my living room. I would like to know if it is possible to have the fireplace and chimney put up against a supporting/load bearing column? that is having the firebox and the chimney all the way up against the supporting column of the house. 
Is there any danger that heat will make the support column weak?

Comment: What part of the world is the house located in, and what material are supporting columns typically made of there?

Comment: hi, the house is in the island of Mauritius. the construction of hte house will be in reinforced concrete. the columns also will be in reinforced concrete, so will be the fire box, layered with bricks inside.

Comment: Just FYI.  This is totally normal in building design.  Chimney's are almost always next to a load bearing wall.  There is nothing inherently wrong with what you are saying given the correct materials are being used.

Answer (score 1):

As always, consult your local building codes, but there shouldn't be an issue with heat on a reinforced concrete column. Whoever draws the plans will need to figure out an appropriate way to tie the column and the chimney together.